# How Can I Assign Panels to Tabs in BaseSiteSetting in Wagtail Admin Panel?

Tags: wagtail

How can I assign panels to specific tabs in `BaseSiteSetting`? In the `Page` class, this is straightforward, as I can simply use this piece of code to create a new panel:

```py
author_panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            FieldPanel("Name"),
        ],
        heading=_("Author(s)"),
    ),
]

@cached_classmethod
def get_edit_handler(self):
    panels = self.get_panels().copy()
    panels += [
        ObjectList(self.author_panels, heading=_("Author(s)")),
    ]

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface(panels)
    return edit_handler.bind_to_model(self)
```

However, in `BaseSiteSetting`, it is not as simple. The only place in the administration panel of `Wagtail` where this is implemented is the `Account` subpage. I really like the elegant division into `Profile` and `Notifications`.

[Account Settings in Wagtail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbh3x.png)

I even looked into the source code of `Wagtail`, but it uses the `forms.ModelForm` class and several helper classes. Is there a simpler way to create tabs for the `BaseSiteSetting` class?

```py
profile_tab = SettingsTab("profile", gettext_lazy("Profile"), order=100)
notifications_tab = SettingsTab(
    "notifications", gettext_lazy("Notifications"), order=200
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom settings panel by extending the BaseSettingPanel class. For example, let's say you want to create a panel for social media links:

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel

@register_setting
class SocialMediaSettings(BaseSetting):
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('facebook'),
            FieldPanel('twitter'),
            FieldPanel('instagram'),
        ], heading='Social Media Links')
    ]
```

Register the custom settings panel in the wagtail_hooks.py file:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register, ModelAdminGroup)
from wagtail.contrib.settings import hooks as settings_hooks
from .models import SocialMediaSettings

@modeladmin_register
class SocialMediaSettingsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = SocialMediaSettings
    menu_icon = 'fa-cog'
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu = True
    exclude_from_explorer = True

class SettingsHooks:
    def construct_settings_panel(self, parent, request):
        return parent.add_child_instance(SocialMediaSettings())

settings_hooks.register(SettingsHooks)
```

In the BaseSiteSetting model, include the custom settings panel by overriding the panels attribute:

```
class BaseSiteSettings(ClusterableModel, models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text=_("The name of your site"))
    ...

    panels = [
        ...
        SocialMediaSettings.panels,
    ]
```

Comment: Could you show me a code snippet or a working example?

You mentioned that it is necessary to extend `BaseSettingPanel`, but in the example, you are extending `BaseSiteSettings`. Then, you are using the `BaseSiteSettings` class instead of `BaseSettingPanel`. So, to be honest, I don't understand much of it, and it doesn't work in my project.